# Unable to respond to threatened delete of question

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I posted [a lengthy question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352292/make-test-disabled-vim) where I tried to summarize my problem while meticulously documenting each step.

Several people asked for clarifying questions regarding my question, and I responded to each one, individually.

In the end a solution was found for that answered my question. However, the last comment appears to be a threat that the question may need to be deleted. Following this apparent threat is a moderator comment warning me to avoid discussions in the comment, but as I apparently do not have enough reputation to start a chat, not leaving me any way to respond.

From my perspective:

- I invested a lot of time in the question. It was a real life problem that I searched for an answer to and was unable to find a solution elsewhere.
- I did my best to meticulously document what I did in order to benefit the community and hopefully save someone from making any of the mistakes that I made, but also for didactic purposes.
- I followed the advice given by each respondent and politely reported my results.

**My Question is two fold**

1. What did I do wrong? (There is probably something obvious as I have gotten very little sleep while trying to learn vim, but I don't see it.)
2. How can I assure that my question is not deleted?

Again I want to say that I am thankful for each person that responded to my original post as the answers were very educational and informative.

Comment: The first thing to keep in mind: Comments are ephemeral! An answer (or question) should be able to stand on its own. Incorporate suggestions and clarifications from the comments and flag them as "obsolete".

Comment: If a question requires a lengthy discussion in comments to reach a solution, it was likely a poorly researched question, or you should have included more information from the get go. We shouldn't have to repeatedly ask for more information..

Comment: What did I do wrong?  Use Vim:(

Comment: @Deduplicator — Thank you. I don't want to hurt someone's reputation for having gone to the trouble of trying to help me. When they commented, it was relevant. Wouldn't my marking their comment as obsolete somehow hurt them?

Comment: @KevinB I agree that it was poorly researched, but not due to lack of effort. my results for "make test" kept coming up with academic web sites.

Comment: @MartinJames Ugh :)

Comment: No. The highest compliment you can pay a comment is heeding its advice. After that, it has accomplished its goal.

Comment: Thank you @Deduplicator I have updated my answer as per your suggestions.

Comment: We don't make threats here, only assertions.

Comment: What did I do wrong: well for one it is probably a while since you looked up the definition of "threat" :)

Comment: Related to: whatever question was posted not long ago about allowing low-rep users to join chatrooms about their own dang questions.

Comment: Upvote here and you're doing your best to rectify the situation and get a positive result. No hard feelings. Hope you work it out. That being said, if your research went no further than Googling "make test", then I'm sorry but you didn't try hard enough!

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful comments. I have thought much on how my question was unclear.  "I ran `make test` from within the ../vim/src folder and now I can not open vim. Nor can I recompile from source. What do I do to get vim working again?" The explanation following my question included all the steps I took in getting to my problem along with links to several articles. I repeated the original question at the bottom in case there was confusion. The comments asked for information that led me to a solution to my question. My sincere apologies for not understanding how this is inappropriate.

Comment: I have updated the OP with the information contained in the comments as suggested here.

Comment: Your answer as currently posted indicates to me you don't know the answer.  Something is working now, but you're not quite sure what fixed it.  It was this... or that... whatever.    That's not a very satisfying answer.   In the future, nobody actually cares whether vim is working for you or not.  But a crisp recipe that's easy to follow, starting from an understandable configuration (clean OS load, or what have you) complete, and works, would probably be useful to others.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Thank you for removing this for me. I am used to a different forum where that was standard practice. In 15 hours as soon as I am able to accept the answer, I will do so.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, Yes, crisp recipes are always better, but they take a lot more work to confirm and double-check. As it is, I think his answer could be still useful to someone who's facing a similar problem (even if BrianWilson never improves on it).

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have tried to update my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 9):

> What did I do wrong?

Well the comment you're referring to stated that your question was unclear, and the fact that people were constantly asking questions of you that necessitated you adding more information to the question, it seems that the question really was unclear.

> How can I assure that my question is not deleted?

Clarify it so that it *becomes* clear.

Answer (score 6):

You read the comment as a "threat". It was not one. It was an observation.

Solution: heed the observation by fixing the question.

I concede that it is unfortunate you could not join the comment-migration chatroom. There's a bug/feature-request open on meta somewhere about that: despite your low rep, you should *definitely* be able to do that on your own posts.

Answer (score 5):

Questions ought to be put "On hold" as unclear, rather than immediately deleted, so that the OP has the opportunity to fix the question.

<s>If it's deleted, then the OP doesn't have the ability to fix the question, because they'd lack the ability to access its contents.</s> It's harder for a deleted question to be undeleted than for a closed question to get un-closed, because not as many community members have the ability to see deleted questions as to re-open closed questions.

Comment: OP still can see and edit a deleted question.

Comment: @NickVolynkin I didn't know that. I've added another rationale for my answer.